# Laravel - Facade explanation and code example

Tags: laravel

whenever we call a Facade Method it involves Facade design pattern and it called for some hidden class by using Facade. for instance for File, if we call

```
File::get(public_path().'test.txt');
```

this will call the method in class

```
Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem
```

and in this class we will have get($path) method.

Now my question is how Facade Abstract Class is related to File and Filesystem and where Laravel is telling them to call get in Filesystem. is there some kind of register which i am missing ?? i want to find complete link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go in your `config/app.php`, you will notice that there's an array called `aliases` which looks like this

```
'aliases' => [
    // 
    //
    //
    //
    'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class, 
];
```

So, basically whenever you call `File`, the [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container) will try to resolve an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class` which is just a Facade.

If you look into `Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class`, you will see that it contains only one method:

```
class File extends Facade
{
    /**
    * Get the registered name of the component.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'files';
    }
}
```

As you can see, it extends the `Facade` class and whenever a Facade is being resolved, Laravel will try to find a *key* in the Service Container that is equal to whatever is returned by `getFacadeAccessor()`.

If you check the source of `Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider`, you will see this:

```
$this->app->singleton('files', function () {
    return new Filesystem;
});
```

As you can see, the key `files` is being bounded to a `FileSystem` implementation. So, that's how Laravel knows how to resolve the `File` facade.

Comment: what do you mean by this? whenever a Facade is being resolved? how exactly a Facade is resolved? and what is Service Container?

Comment: Here's a very good article on [understanding the laravel service container](https://m.dotdev.co/understanding-laravel-service-container-bd488ca05280)